# Can't add .NET 4.0 Assembly Reference In MonoDevelop 2.4.1

Tags: .net-4.0, mono, assemblies, monodevelop

I've installed MonoDevelop 2.4.1 With Mono 2.8.1.
My trouble is that i can't add assembly reference to assembly compiled for .NET 4.0 (on same MonoDevelop IDE).

What am i do. References -> Edit References -> .NET Assembly -> Browse to file & select it

Than MD displays an error that an assembly that i'm trying to add isn't .NET assembly.
I've set profile to .NET 4.0 everywhere.

Reflector disassembles my assembly fine so it's ok.
My OS is Windows 7
What's wrong?

**UPD:**
Posted a bug to Novell. Here it is https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=659894

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When i do `"C:\Program Files\Mono-2.8.1\bin\mono.exe" "C:\Program Files\MonoDevelop\bin\MonoDevelop.exe"` the problem disapears.

It's understood that by running MonoDevelop.exe it runs on Microsoft .NET and the issue is that MonoDevelop (.NET 2.0 assembly) can't recognize an assembly (.NET 4.0) with use of 2.0 APIs.

Lets look at code (MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.AssemblyReferencePanel):

```
private void SelectReferenceDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] array = new string[this.chooser.Filenames.Length];
    this.chooser.Filenames.CopyTo(array, 0);
    foreach (string str in array)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        try
        {
            AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Path.GetFullPath(str));
        }
        catch
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            this.selectDialog.AddReference(new ProjectReference(ReferenceType.Assembly, str));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageService.ShowError(GettextCatalog.GetString("File '{0}' is not a valid .Net Assembly", str));
        }
    }
}
```

The line `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Path.GetFullPath(str));` is a source of all evil.
I'm going to post a bug report to novell. Or it's not a bug?

Comment: It's a bug, please file it. We should use Mono.Cecil to read the assembly name, like we do in the core runtime handling code.

Comment: Ok. I'll do it asap. The link will be here. Btw running MD directly on mono doesn't allow me to build my projects because one of my add-ins throws TypeLoadExceptions :( Will wait for a fix

Comment: Michael, thank you for a bug fix! Recently there was a release 2.4.2 of MonoDevelop, but your bug fix seems not to be included - the problem still apears. Don't you know when to expect the release fixing this bug?

Comment: I didn't backport it, but it won't be long until the MonoDevelop 2.6 beta is out.