# How can I deserialize a JSON string in Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, json, mono

How can I deserialize a JSON string in C# (Mono)?

Is there a JSON library and instructions on how to install it? I'm using fedora 14.

Comment: I assume that the json contract serializer is available on mono too. And Json.net might work on mono too. No idea why you mention your IDE.

Comment: @CodesInChaos since when is Fedora an "IDE"? Do you even acronym, bro?

Comment: @user3791372 [monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) is an IDE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

we are not utilizing json contract serializer - instead we use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). it should work with mono too.
you don't need to install the assembly, just add a reference and supply it with your final package!

**EDIT:**
how to add a reference? though i'm not a mono-devlop-er ... taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450766/cant-add-net-4-0-assembly-reference-in-monodevelop-2-4-1):

> References -> Edit References -> .NET
>   Assembly -> Browse to file & select it

otherwise: hey, just hit `F1`!

Comment: can you pls tell me how to reference the json.net inside a monodevelop project ?

Comment: Seems like every answer I see on StackOverflow regarding using Json.NET neglects to state something very important, that to use Json.NET classes in your C# code you need to add the statement "using Newtonsoft.Json;" at the top of your file. I suppose you could fully qualify the classes but even the Json.Net website seems to neglect stating this. Anyway, for those of you (like me) for whom this isn't obvious, do this to use the classes in that package.

Comment: @Marc actually I've recently started to qualify my code - anyway, doesn't visual studio show up a mark you can click on, to select a proper `using` ... sry, I have little vanilla experience due to the use of ReSharper, which btw offers such a feature.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend looking at [ServiceStack.NET Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text). It is incredibly fast compared to JSON.NET.

Examples of serializing a dictionary:

*ServiceStack.NET*

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer<Dictionary<String, Object>>();
var result = jsonSerializer.SerializeToString(dict);
```

*JSON.NET*

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Take a look at JSON.NET:**

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

**Features:**

- Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON
- LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON
- High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers
- Write indented, easy to read JSON
- Convert JSON to and from XML

**Example to serialize and deserialize:**

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    ...

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }

    void PersonToJsonToPersonExample ()
    {
        var person = new Person { Name = "Bob", Birthday = new DateTime (1987, 2, 2) };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (person);
        Console.WriteLine ("JSON representation of person: {0}", json);

        var person2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person> (json);
        Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1}", person2.Name, person2.Birthday);
    }
```