# How do I use JSON.Net on a new Mono class library?

Tags: json, macos, mono, monodevelop, json.net

I wish to use `JSON.Net` on a brand spankin new `Mono class library` (say .. `Mono / .NET 4`). Of course, this class library will be used by a MonoTouch iPhone/iPad project (also in the same solution).

**I'm not sure of the steps I need to do, to use JSON.Net in a `Mono Class Library`**.

The closest I got to [this was this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437809/how-can-i-deserialize-a-json-in-mono) .. but it said nothing about how the DLL was made, where it exists, etc.

BTW: I'm also using MonoDevelop for the IDE. This is on a Mac OSX.

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly is the problem? JSON.NET is a normal class library that you can use like any other. What did you try and how did that fail?

Comment: I echo the comment by @svick. If you're having trouble locating the binary just head over to the NuGet gallery - http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: What i'm asking is -> what are the steps to use JSON.NET with a mono class library? Do I just download the binary from NuGet? and reference that?

Comment: Because there's no way to download a package manually, from nuget.org ... which is why i'm confused and not sure of the process...

Comment: @Pure.Krome, then download it from [the JSON.NET site](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Ah - so we need to download the source, compile it under mono .. then just reference that mono-compiled dll, normally?

Comment: You can do that if you want, but you can also just download the pre-compiled binary and use that. As I understand it, that's one of the key goals driving Mono - the ability to execute compiled-on-Windows .NET code as-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your mono is new enough, you can in fact use NuGet downloaded from [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939). You also need some trusted certificates to get it working well - they can be imported using:

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove
```

And then you can download the package using NuGet

You can also download the library any other way - no need to recompile the sources as Mono and .NET are binary compatible.

Btw, binaries *can* be directly downloaded from nuget in a way like that:
[Json.Net](https://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Newtonsoft.Json).

Comment: but .. that nuget command line is a windows binary ... and i'm on a Mac :)

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Not quite, it is .NET binary and you can run it using mono NuGet.exe As said in comments, binary compatibility is one of the key goals of mono. Btw, you can also use the link I provided (or any constructed like that).

Comment: also .. David Fowler (from NuGet / SignalR / MS Employee) also got NuGet Package Restore working for VS2010 sln files, last night. I tested his changes out on my mac using xbuild. Packages downloaded :) And with binary compatibility .... I sense lots and lots of Win!